# How do I post to named route using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In routes.rb I define:

```
post '/api/create-entities-for-date-tags', to: 'bulk_update#create_entities_for_date_tags', as: 'createdates'
```

in my rspec test I have:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe BulkUpdateController do

  describe 'routing' do
    it "routes to #index" do
      post createdates_path, {}
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test, the output is:

```
 Failure/Error: post createdates_path, {}
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"bulk_update", :action=>"/api/create-entities-for-date-tags"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to add `as: 'createdates'` to the route you defined to make it work as spec'd.

Or, change the way you're referring to the route in your spec, to match the path in your route. (`rake routes` can be useful when you want the exact names of your routes.)

Comment: Sorry, the two files were out of sync when I copied them. I do have the as: 'createdates' and it has the same error. Thanks.

Comment: I wondered if that might be the case. Is your controller defined in an `Api` namespace? Such as `module Api class BulkUpdateController < ApplicationController end end`?

Comment: It isn't, it is just class BulkUpdateController < ApplicationController.